# Evitar autenticação de rotas tardiamente com JWT

Tags: node.js, express.js, jwt

O JWT nos permite através do método `unless` informar URLs e métodos de requisições que não devem vir a ser exigida autenticação.

Porém até onde sei é necessário que isso seja feito quando o Middleware é informado para o ExpressJS já nas primeiras fases de configuração.

Há como informar tardiamente, quando se define rotas em outros módulos para isentar sub-rotas da autenticação.